# Symfony DateTimeType input texts attr (date_widget and time_widget)

Tags: php, symfony

I created form type with DateTimeType.
I separated datetime to 2 widgets (text inputs).

How can I format text inputs with attr options? (I want add date class to date widget and time class to time widget)

And how can I validate it separately?

```
     $builder->add( 'valid_to', DateTimeType::class,
                    array(  'required'=>false,
                            'label'=>'Valid vége',
                            'html5'=>false,
                            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
                            'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
                            'constraints'=>array(   new DateTime(array("message"=>"Invalid datetime. [need: yyyy-mm-dd] [hh:mm]")),
                            ),
                            'attr'=>array('class'=>'datetimepicker',
                            )));
```

This is a html response:

```
<div id="email_template_content_valid_to" class="datetimepicker">
    <input type="text" id="email_template_content_valid_to_date" name="email_template_content[valid_to][date]" value="2016-08-24" />
    <input type="text" id="email_template_content_valid_to_time" name="email_template_content[valid_to][time]" value="00:00" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's not possible to define specific attributes like "class" to only one of the widget of DateTimeType (@see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11824)

You must defined your own DateTimeType class to pass specific options for time or date widget like this for example (not tested yet):

```
//  Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType

// Only pass a subset of the options to children
$dateOptions = array_intersect_key($options, array_flip(array(
    'years',
    'months',
    'days',
    'empty_value',
    'placeholder',
    'required',
    'translation_domain',
    'html5',
    'invalid_message',
    'invalid_message_parameters',
    'date_attr' // <= attr for date widget
)));

$timeOptions = array_intersect_key($options, array_flip(array(
    'hours',
    'minutes',
     'seconds',
     'with_minutes',
     'with_seconds',
     'empty_value',
     'placeholder',
     'required',
     'translation_domain',
     'html5',
     'invalid_message',
     'invalid_message_parameters',
     'time_attr' // <= attr for time widget
)));
```

---

```
$builder->add('valid_to', DateTimeType::class, [
    'required'    => false,
    'label'       => 'Valid vége',
    'html5'       => false,
    'date_widget' => 'single_text',
    'time_widget' => 'single_text',
    'format'      => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
    'constraints' => [
        new DateTime(["message" => "Invalid datetime. [need: yyyy-mm-dd] [hh:mm]"]),
    ],
    'date_attr'   => ['class' => 'my_date_class'],
    'time_attr'   => ['class' => 'my_time_class']
 ]);
```